# como harían para que el método de quicksort ordene de forma descendente

Tags: c

```
#include<Stdio.h>
#include<Stdlib.h>
void qs(int A[], int inf, int sup){
   int izq, der, mitad, x;
   izq=inf;
   der=sup;
   mitad=A[(izq+der)/2];
   do{
       while(A[izq]<mitad && izq<sup)
       izq++;
       while(mitad<A[der] && der>inf)
       der--;
       if(izq<=der){
           x=A[izq];
           A[izq]=A[der];
           A[der]=x;
           izq++;
           der--;
       }
   }
   while(izq<=der);
   if(inf<der)
      qs(A,inf,der);
   if(izq<sup)
      qs(A,izq,sup);
}
void Quicksort(int A[], int n){
   int i=0;
   qs(A, i, n-1);
}
main(){
   int lista[]={8,2,5,6,1,11,9};
   int x;
   qs(lista,0,6);
   for(x=0;x<6;x++){
        printf("%d-",lista[x]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probá cambiando los signos de mayor a menor:

```
while(A[izq]>mitad && izq<sup)
   izq++;
while(A[der]<mitad && der>inf)
   der--;
```

Comment: gracias amiga me sirvio

Answer (score 1):

De esta forma es mucho mas simple:

```
#include<Stdio.h>
#include<Stdlib.h>

int comp (const void * elem1, const void * elem2){
    int f = *((int*)elem1);
    int s = *((int*)elem2);
    if (f < s) return  1;
    if (f > s) return -1;
    return 0;
}

int main(){
   int lista[]={8,2,5,6,1,11,9};
   int x;
   qsort (lista, sizeof(lista)/sizeof(*lista), sizeof(*lista), comp);
   for(x=0;x<6;x++){
        printf("%d-",lista[x]);
   }
}
```